# How do I install Adobe Air using "Ubuntu Software Centre"

Tags: software-installation, adobe-air

I tried:

1. Launching Ubuntu Software Centre
2. I typed in "air" and found "adobe air"
3. It says "available from the 'maverick-partner' source. and has a button "use this source"
4. I clicked "use this source", I saw a "in progress (1)" icon come up in the side bar, and disappear, but nothing happened/changed.

I'm stuck.

I have actually already added the maverick-partner source to apt so I could install sun-java6-jdk.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 are you aware that Adobe Air was dumped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to install Adobe AIR on Ubuntu 13.10

[Instructions for Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/394140/172367)

## How to install Adobe AIR on Ubuntu 10.10

I have looked into this and on the official Adobe Air 2 page for Linux, 64-bit binaries are not available, although 32-bit should work fine.

Try going through the steps on this page here:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/521/cpsid_52132.html

Although they are intended for 9.04, I can't see why this wouldn't work on 10.10.

If following those steps don't work, try this article on OMG!Ubuntu!:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-install-adobe-air-on-ubuntu-64bit-2/

Comment: I've followed steps like that before - and I could do that again - but since Adobe Air is in the "Ubuntu Software Centre" I thought I should use that. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: This tutorial worked well for me: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-install-adobe-air-on-ubuntu-64bit-2/

Comment: Same for me - just be sure to download the .bin version and run chmod 744 on it to make it executable.

Comment: PS: I had to reinstall flash afterwards...

Answer (score 2):

## How to install Adobe Air in Ubuntu 13.10

There are 2 ways to install Adobe Air on Ubuntu 13.10.

1. Install it using wine
2. Install it using outdated Linux installer.

## Using wine

The easyest way is to use Playonlinux. Please note that some functions will not work.

## Outdated Linux Installer

Please note that adobe AIR is no longer officially supported. Installing it requires an enormous amount of hacking **which can make your system unstable.**

### ia32-libs

Adobe AIR depends on the ia32-libs package. However, that package was dropped for Ubuntu 13.10. This should not be a problem because there are other packages that do the exact same thing, however, older software thinks this is a problem. With .deb packages, you can just repackage them and remove the ia32-libs dependency. Seeing as this installer is a .bin blob, the only way to do it is to install ia32-libs manually.

Download the ia-32-libs package from the raring repository and install it manually: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/ia32-libs/download

### Other dependencies

use the "Get Libs" utility. to grab the 32-bit libraries that your package manager will not allow to co-exist with your 64-bit ones.

```
wget http://jeffhendricks.net/getlibs-all.deb
```

Install "Get Libs" and grab our libraries.

```
sudo dpkg -i getlibs-all.deb
sudo getlibs -l libhal-storage.so.1
sudo getlibs -l libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

Install the required package dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libhal-storage1 libgnome-keyring0 lib32nss-mdns
```

Make a symbolic link between the 32-bit libraries installed by Get Libs, and the location they are expected to be found in. (one of these two might not work on your system, I'm not sure which one)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
```

### Actual adobe AIR installation

Download the Adobe AIR installer:

```
wget http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

Make it excecutable

```
chmod +x ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

And finally, Install Adobe AIR itself

```
sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
```

source: www.thepowerbase.com/2013/06/how-to-install-adobe-air-in-ubuntu-13-04/
source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181649

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Adobe Air download [page](http://get.adobe.com/air/), and select the .deb version in the pull down menu, let it download and install like you would any other .deb file.

[Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-install-adobe-air-on-ubuntu-64bit-2/) is a howto explaining how to install 32bit Adobe Air, on 64bit Ubuntu.... It doesn't look like here is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Ok, I could try that, but, I think I really meant to ask "How do I install Adobe Air from the software centre"

Comment: You would have to find a PPA, which I am not aware of one... but just because I don't know it doesn't mean it doesn't exist...

Comment: I tried this, the .deb file opened up in software center and said "Wrong architecture 'i386'"

Comment: Regarding a PPA - presumably there is a deb file and package already - why else would "Adobe Air" be in the Ubuntu software center?

Comment: I didn't realize it was already in there, sorry, also, just because it is in there, doesn't mean it is a current/up-dated version. also, I added a new link in my original answer detailing how to install Air on a 64bit install.

Comment: Presumably if its there, it should work, shouldn't it?  Or at least fail to work with some kind of error.

Comment: It could be broken...

Comment: It does seem like its broken :(

Answer (score 1):

The partner repository has been causing trouble recently to some users when installing Adobe Flash, because the connection times out and the installation is interrupted. So I suspect you are experiencing the same problem in regard to Adobe Air. Try again later or download the deb file from [Adobe](http://get.adobe.com/air/) directly.

Comment: I've tried four or five times. I'll try again in a bit.  I tried downloading the deb file from Adobe, it failed to install "Wrong architecture 'i386'"

Comment: Shouldn't the software-center give me an error message of some kind?

Comment: To be honest, I don't use the Software Center :) I just tried on a 64bit VM and got "Sorry, 'Adobe Air' is not available for this type of computer (amd64)."

Comment: Interesting, thats at least somewhat helpful :)

Comment: Yep, you should try the tutorial provided by TheX

Answer (score 0):

I used [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~dajhorn/+archive/adobeair). It has the 64-bit package.

To add the ppa and install Adobe Air run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dajhorn/adobeair
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install adobeair
```

You could just run the first two lines of code then install it in the software center if you wish :)

Comment: That PPA seems not to be maintained, the latest (and only) version from that PPA is 2.5.1.17730, Adobe has 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to download the .deb package from the official repos or website.then you may use Gdebi package installer(available in USC) to install adobe air.

i have tried this for many apps that don't install properly from USC.it works in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I second @Galgalesh's answer to use Wine because I was unlucky trying approaches to install Adobe AIR natively on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Wine works for me instead.

Here are my steps for installing Adobe AIR on Ubuntu 14.04LTS which I am using to run time management app Klok (from getklok.com - https://askubuntu.com/a/563302/7072 ):-

I used the free WineHQ software which enables many Windows applications to run on Ubuntu.

Steps:

1) Installing WINE, part 1 of 2: I ensured a pre-requisite package was installed https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

2) Installing WINE, part 2 of 2: I then installed WineHQ from the commandline, issued command: sudo apt-get build-dep wine1.6

3) Installing Adobe AIR - part 1 of 2: I downloaded Adobe Air from here http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html

4) Installing Adobe AIR - part 2 of 2: I right clicked on the downloaded air16_win.exe file, from: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html From the pop-up menu, I selected Open With, then selected Wine Windows Program Manager and followed the steps from there.