# ia32-libs package not found intalling Adobe Air

Tags: adobe-air

I need to install adobe air in my Ubuntu 13.10 x64. The installation shows this error,

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adobeair:
 adobeair depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
```

Now I tried to install `ia32-libs`,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Now the error shows,

```
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

And also tried,

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs:i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch:i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 gcc-4.6-base:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Is there any working solution?

[This solution](http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-13-10) also not working for me.

Comment: No working solution here.

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/179818/114818) work for you. Please [edit] your question with its results.

Comment: No, this also not working.

Comment: from where you downloaded adobe air?

Comment: from launchpad.net. I think it was from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobeair/1:2.6.0.19170-0lucid1

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/11570/172367

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air is not supported in Linux (hence Ubuntu) anymore, that package was not prepared for being multi-arch ready, and that's why you get errors. I wasn't able to install Adobe Air in my 64-bit system by any **sane means**. You may be get lucky to find a version that still work, but **that's under your own risk.**

Comment: Now solved this issue using little hacky way. Installed adobe air and balsamiq mockup windows installer using wine. Now everything working.