# How to install Klok 2 time management software on Adobe AIR with Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, wine, adobe-air

How to do this using Adobe AIR running on Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Klok working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I used the free WineHQ software which enables many Windows applications to run on Ubuntu.

Steps:

1) Installing WINE, part 1 of 2: I ensured a pre-requisite package was installed
https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

2) Installing WINE, part 2 of 2: I then installed WineHQ from the commandline, issued command:
sudo apt-get build-dep wine1.6

3) Installing Adobe AIR - part 1 of 2: I downloaded Adobe Air from here
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html

4) Installing Adobe AIR - part 2 of 2: I right clicked on the downloaded air16_win.exe file, from: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html
From the pop-up menu, I selected Open With, then selected Wine Windows Program Manager and followed the steps from there.

5) Then I downloaded Klok from the 'Download Now' link on http://getklok.com/features.html#versions

6) I right clicked on the download Klok2.air file and from the pop up menu, selected Open With Adobe AIR application installer. And followed the Klok installation instructions as per usual.

This screenshot shows Klok 2 working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Klok 2 is running on Adobe Air 16 which is running on WINE): https://www.flickr.com/photos/therobyouknow/15868611448/

[image]